# Forbid an exe to read part of memory

Tags: windows, memory, exe

There is a program that scans the memory of my machine to find what programs I am using. I want to avoid this.

Is there any solution to forbid this other program from checking my memory, so it will only see its own memory?
I'm using windows.

Comment: This does not seem to be a programming question specifically. Also, I get the feeling that the motive is to defeat anticheating mechanisms used by various online games.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I know of for one process to read another process's memory is via [`ReadProcessMemory()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680553.aspx), which requires the reading process to use [`OpenProcess()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684320.aspx) to obtain `PROCESS_VM_READ` permission to the process being read.  So, presumably that is succeeding, which means the reading process has adequate permission to access your app's memory, such as if the reading app is running as an admin, or is a debugger.  In which case, there is not much your app can do to block it, except either alter its own security descriptor via `SetSecurityInfo()` (but `OpenProcess()` allows debuggers to bypass that descriptor and gain full access), or set your app to run with a higher integrity level (Vista and later only) than the reading app uses so that `PROCESS_VM_READ` permission is denied.

Refer to MSDN for more details:

[Process Security and Access Rights](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684880.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I always use the sandbox that comes with Avast Antivirus (www.avast.com).  It allows you to run applications in a completely isolated environment.